# Is it possible to call a method of a locked object from another thread?

Tags: java, concurrency

when thread 1 has the intrinsic lock of an object because of

```
synchronized(object) {
...
}
```

is it possible to call

```
object.method()
```

from thread 2 or not respectively do I need to type

```
synchronized(object) {
object.method();
}
```

in thread 2 to prevent it from calling the method while thread 1 is holding the lock?

In my case I got ConcurrentModificationExceptions while iterating over a Map and I tried to prevent modifications from other threads by locking the map. And I know that often the reason for ConcurrentModificationExceptions is that the map is changed during iteration but I'm quite sure that this is not the case in my case because there are only "get"-statements and one method call in the iteration, so there can't happen any modification.

Thanks in advance.

Binabik

Comment: Care to share the code of your method? Maybe there's something in it that you hadn't thought of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronization in Java is entirely co-operative - if the second thread doesn't choose to try to acquire the monitor (and if there's nothing in the method which tries to do so) then it won't automatically lock.

It's not that the object "is locked" - it's that one thread owns the lock associated with the object. The object itself can still be accessed; if it doesn't need the lock, it won't block.

Note that you can get a `ConcurrentModificationException` even within a single thread if you try to iterate over it and change it within the same loop, e.g.

```
// Not safe: will throw an exception
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().equals("foo")) {
        map.put("bar", "Hello");
    }
}
```

It's possible that this is what's going on in your code, but we can't tell as you haven't *shown* us any code. If you can present a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, we're much more likely to be able to work out what's going on.

Comment: And now I'm feeling again like an idiot because I wrote that I'm "quite sure there's no modification". But there was a method call to a listener which called a public method of my class where the modification occured. But in my defence this modification was quite hidden.

Answer (score 1):

When you acquire a lock, it only prevents other threads from acquiring the same lock.  It does not lock the object as such and you can access its methods.

If you got a ConcurrentModicationException, then you have a concurrent modification.  If you don't know where this is happening, you need to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Unless object.method() is synchronized you can call it from an other thread. You have to be careful when using a iteration over a non-synchronized map. You should use a synchronzied map and synchronize over the iteration; otherwise you have to synchronize all write actions as well.

Comment: But if I initialized my Map with Map map = Collections.synchronizedMap( ... ) the methods of my map are synchronized, or? And if I synchronize the iteration over the map, then it should be safe?